# modbus TCP to STM32 connection

Tags: stm32, modbus-tcp

the problem is continueing - I can succesfully connect to MACH3 however when I try to write to holding registers MACH3 gives receive timeout - MACH3 doesnot like my response

the checksum is correct as you can see - please advise what can I do - thanks

[wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHmBA.png)

I corrected checksum - I tried with TCP client SW of simplymodbus - again write operation without success - I am sure the packet arrives at STM32 becouse I can turn on off LED at STM32 side with modbus write operation